# Filter Date with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

[[image: This is column in workbook date and i want count the data from this workbook to another workbookThis workbook]I need some help how to count date in another workbook with VBA.

```vb
Sub countMacro()
    Dim oWBWithColumn As Workbook: Set oWBWithColumn = Application.Workbooks.Open("D:\U2000\Taishan01\Dump\Taishan01_0428.xlsx")
    Dim oWS As Worksheet: Set oWS = oWBWithColumn.Worksheets("CurrentAlarms20210428102131871_")
    Dim intLastRow As Long: intLastRow = oWS.Cells(Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D2").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(oWS.Range("J7:J" & intLastRow), "<2021")

    oWBWithColumn.Close False

    Set oWS = Nothing
    Set oWBWithColumn = Nothing
End Sub
```

This is my code I want filter date `<2021` and between 2 date `01-01-2021` to `04-01-2021`. Please kindly help.  Because I want to try is can't run.

Comment: `CountA` counts everything... Try using `CountIf`. But should we understand that in the analized range are there `Date`?

Comment: I'll try to CountIF but same, can't run.

Comment: instead of `"<2021"` try `"<" & cStr(DateSerial(2021, 1, 1))` with `CountIf`

Comment: Please kindly help.

Comment: Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(oWS.Range("J7:J" & intLastRow), "<" & CStr(DateSerial(2021, 1, 1)))  I have tried but the results are wrong, the result should be 9 but this is only 0.

Comment: then your dates in your column are no real dates but text. What is the result of the following in the immediate window `Debug.Print cDbl(oWS.Range("J7"))`?

Comment: so I took the data in another workbook, and created a count report in the new workbook. J7 is the column in the date workbook.

Comment: Please, try `Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(oWS.Range("J7:J" & intLastRow), "<" & CLng(DateSerial(2021, 1, 1)))`. Excel keeps `Date` as `Long`...

Comment: @FaneDuru That won't help as the `CLng` will be cast into a string anyway. So dosn't matter if you cast a `date` into a `long` into a ̀ string` or a `date` into a `string` (just one conversion less). Because you concatenate the long with a string `"<" &` there is an implicit conversion.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ: In order to **Count if value is less then something** the function needs the value to be searched and compared. Even if it is expressed as a string. Please, try it...

Comment: @FaneDuru mehhh you are right. VBA tries to think and converts it into a string like if you used  `format`. It has to be converted to `Long` first.

Comment: So, what should I do?

Comment: Can you tell us something about the date interval you intend processing? I mean, something like from **25th of January, 2019 to first of June, 2022**...

Comment: I have tried this code but same, Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(oWS.Range("J7:J" & intLastRow), "<" & CLng(DateSerial(2021, 1, 1)))

Comment: I asked you about the date interval... If your date range contains date bigger the first of January 2021, the result is correct. 0 (zero), I mean...

Comment: I want to process dates less than 01 January 2021, and between 01 January 2021 to 01 May 2021.

Comment: yes, it is true there is a date greater than 01 January 2021. but I want to find a date before January 1, 2021, for example, December 2019 like that.

Comment: But does such a previous date exist in the range you try analyzing? If yes, I am afraid that it only looks like a date but in fact is a string...

Comment: yes it's in the date data.

Comment: @HanaLarasati If that does not work please add `MsgBox cDbl(oWS.Range("J7"))` right before this line  `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")…` in your code. And tell what the result in the message box is or if it throws an error tell which. We need to find out if your dates are numeric or text.

Comment: MsgBox CDbl(oWS.Range("J7"))
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D2").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(oWS.Range("J7:J" & intLastRow), "<" & CLng(DateSerial(2021, 1, 1))) Like this?

Comment: Notification error " Type mismatch"

Comment: So, `oWS.Range("J7")` is not a date... Please, edit your question and place a picture (at least, if not something editable) of the range you try processing.

Comment: OK so the issue is that your dates are text looking like dates, but not numeric dates. You can only work with dates properly if they are real numeric dates. So you need to convert them in the cells into numeric dates. There is no way around that. Are there formulas in column J or did you put the date there?

Comment: @Pᴇʜ: Theoretically, if their text representation is done in a way to be correctly converted to `Date` (without mixing day with month), based on the localization, the range can be placed in an array and evaluate each converted date against the limitations and count the ones inside the interval. I required to see the range in discussion but she does not show it... But the assumption about the date conversion is correct, a simple `TextToColumn` conversion should make them `Date`...

Comment: @FaneDuru any automatic conversion will only work properly if the date format of the operating system matches the date format of the strings in that column. I assume that is not the case otherwise Excel would not have put them as strings but as dates in the first place. If they don't match either you end up still having strings or messed up dates. The only secure way is to manually convert them (using formula or VBA) by stripping the strings down by its seperators and rebuilding them using `DateSerial`.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ: I agree... It may depend of the way the date range has been imported, the used date separator etc. But it may be risky, I agree again.

Comment: @Hana Larasati Can you edit your question and show us how the range containing text as Date looks. We maybe will be able to help you with the conversion, too. Some VBA, too...

Answer (score 0):

When you will have the range converted to `Date`, please use the next (adapted) code:

```
Sub countMacro()
    Dim oWBWithColumn As Workbook: Set oWBWithColumn = Application.Workbooks.Open("D:\U2000\Taishan01\Dump\Taishan01_0428.xlsx")
    Dim oWS As Worksheet: Set oWS = oWBWithColumn.Worksheets("CurrentAlarms20210428102131871_")
    Dim intLastRow As Long: intLastRow = oWS.cells(oWS.rows.count, "J").End(xlUp).row
    
    Dim firstD As Long, endD As Long, rng As Range
    
    Set rng = oWS.Range("J7:J" & intLastRow)
    firstD = CLng(DateSerial(2021, 1, 1))
    endD = CLng(DateSerial(2021, 4, 1))

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D2").value = WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(rng, ">=" & firstD, rng, "<=" & endD)

    oWBWithColumn.Close False
End Sub
```

**Edited**:

In order to convert your text looking like Date, in Date, please use the next code:

```
Sub TransformTextInDate()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, lastR As Long, rngT As Range, arrT, ArrD, arr, i As Long
  
  Set sh = ActiveSheet 'use here the sheet you need, or activate the one to be processed
  lastR = sh.Range("J" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).row
  
  Set rngT = sh.Range("J7:J" & lastR)       'use here your range to be converted in Date
  arrT = rngT.value                                 'load the range in an array
  ReDim ArrD(1 To UBound(arrT), 1 To 1)  'redim the array to keep Date
  
  For i = 1 To UBound(arrT)
        arr = Split(arrT(i, 1), "-") 'split the text by "-"
        ArrD(i, 1) = CDate(left(arr(2), 2) & "/" & arr(1) & "/" & arr(0)) 'build the Date
  Next i
  rngT.Offset(0, 1).EntireColumn.Insert xlLeft  'insert a column to the right of the processed one
  With sh.cells(rngT.row, rngT.Offset(0, 1).Column).Resize(UBound(ArrD), 1)
        .Value2 = ArrD                                  'drop the processed array values at once
        .EntireColumn.AutoFit                         'fit the new column
        .NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"          'format the range in the standard way
  End With
  MsgBox "Converted to Date..."
End Sub
```

The above code will insert a column and drop the processed result in it.

If the conversion is correct, you may delete the previous column, or if you like keeping it (for hours or for something else), you should adapt the first code to make it working on the new column (please, change J to K).

Please, send some feedback after testing the above codes.

Comment: @Hana Larasati: Is the condition "When you will have the range converted to Date" fulfilled?

Comment: @Hana Larasati I asked you three times to show us the range looking like Date, but being text and I did not do it. I am afraid I cannot help in these circumstances...

Comment: No because the result is still 0.

Comment: I have sent a capture range date, I also think that it is text. So how do I filter with VBA if the date data case is in the form of text?

Comment: @Hana Larasati: It was obvious that it is not `Date` after you did what Pᴇʜ suggested. I thought that we were very clear: **You cannot filter the strings as `Date`**!  You have to convert the string in a real `Date` format. Then, you did not say anything about the fact that your Date values contain also hours, minutes and sec. Anyhow, in order to help you converting it you should answer two questions: Which is the standard `Date` format, according to your localization. I mean, if you put a formula "=Now()" and press enter, how the return looks? Then, do you need converting the **ONLY** `Date`?

Comment: I have tried put formula "=Now()", but the result is still 0.

Comment: So how i can convert the string in a real date format and can filter with VBA? any example code?

Comment: Sorry if my question offended you, I didn't mean that. I thank you for your help so far.

But I am also confused, how to change from string to real date and then filter it back as date data. this is the first time for me. so please guide. @faneDuru

Comment: After I put =Now like this 07/05/2021 15:35.

Comment: @Hana Larasati: Now, you answer only one question. What about the second one? How do you need converting it? Only 07/05/2021, or 07/05/2021 12:30:25? Anyhow, the above code deals only with the Date... Now I will leave my office. I will be back in about an hour.

Comment: @Hana Larasati: Still alive? Please, test the code to convert the range to Date. I edited the above answer and added such a code. I am waiting for some feedback...

Comment: @Hana Larsati After more than a month, when you maybe will come back here, it will be good to know that we here, when somebody answer our question in a convenient way, we tick the code left side check box, in order to make it **accepted answer**. In this way, somebody else searching for a similar issue will know that supplied solution works...